# How can I write all values extracted via regex to a file?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I've got a piece of regex which I've tested in JMeter using the regexp tester and it returns multiple results (10), which is what I'm expecting.

I'm using the Regular Expression Extractor to retrieve the values and I would like to write ALL of them to a CSV file. I'm using the Beanshell Post Processor but I am only aware of a method to write 1 value to file.

My script in Beanshell so far:

```java
temp = vars.get("VALUES"); // VALUES is the Reference Name in regex extractor

FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("c:\\downloads\\results.txt",true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write(temp);
out.close();
```

How can I write all the values found via the regex to file? Thanks.

Comment: How is `temp` defined?

Comment: I have not defined temp. I grabbed some code while googling a solution as to how to write to files in JMeter.

Comment: I see where you're going with this though. VALUES is an array so I'd need to define it as an array when I do a vars.get("VALUES"). This is what I'd like to know how to do. Also once we have temp defined as an array how do I dump it's contents to a file? Would I need to write a loop that went through each row of an error? Forgive me if these questions are stupid, I'm just learning this stuff for the first time. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'll look into [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) output, you'll see that `VALUES` will be a prefix.

Like

- VALUES=...
- VALUES_g=...
- VALUES_g0=...
- VALUES_g1=...

etc.

You can use [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to iterate over them.

If you want to proceed with [Beanshell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) - you'll need to iterate through all variables like:

```
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Set;

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("c:\\downloads\\results.txt", true);
    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    Set variables = vars.entrySet();

    for (Map.Entry entry : variables) {
        if (entry.getKey().startsWith("VALUES")) {
            out.write(entry.getValue().toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            out.write(newline.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            out.flush();
        }
    }

    out.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I figured this out by doing exactly what you said. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To write the contents of your values array into the file, the following code should work (untested):

```java
String[] values = vars.get("VALUES");

FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("c:\\downloads\\results.txt", true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
   out.write(values[i]);
   out.newLine();
   out.flush();
}
out.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this did not write anything to file. The results.txt file was created but contained nothing. With the regex extractor I am using the following values: Reference Name: VALUES
Regular Expression: <td class="right">([^<]*)</td>
Template: $1$
Match No. (0 for Random): 1
Default Value: FAIL

Comment: Checked log and saw error: ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``String[] values = vars.get("VALUES");  FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("c:\\ . . . '' : Typed variable declaration 
2014/03/13 12:30:45 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``String[] values = vars.get("VALUES");  FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("c:\\ . . . '' : Typed variable declaration

Comment: I fear I cannot really help beyond that point, since I don't know what those variable values are that you are retrieving from somewhere via some sort of regex (I / we would need more details in order to to continue trying to help). I can only say that if the `String[]` array is properly filled, my code will write it to the file.

Comment: Hi, you're right your code is working fine. I replaced String[] values = vars.get("VALUES") with String[] values = {"a","b","c"} and it worked fine. So the question is how can I retrieve the whole array of results in VALUES from my regex extractor? Thanks

Comment: If you can post some additional lines of code that show the regex part, someone might be able to give you some hints.

Comment: I am not using code to extract the regex part. I use the regular expression extractor component in JMeter. I've mentioned the variables I use to set up this component in a comment above.

Comment: @ratsstack Okay, now I got what you are trying. So, regarding the error: 1. Is `VALUES` the reference name you set in the jMeter regex extractor? 2. Can you test-wise use `System.out.println(vars.get("VALUES"))`, to see if there is anything at all. There also might be a way to query the response code of the extractor, but you said that that part works fine for sure.

Comment: 1) Yes, VALUES is the reference name in JMeter for regex extractor 2) nice suggestion, it only returns ONE value and hence why this is failing. I have solved this problem based on what your answer. I am using multiple regex extractors to get the different values and I write these all to file. Thank you very much for all your help. I may need more later! :-)