# Empty csv file while using BeanShell Postprocessor

Tags: csv, testing, jmeter

i'm trying to save my variables into a csv file by using BeanShell Postprocessor, Code:

```
String id = "${userID}";
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("JmeterBean.csv",true);
fstream.write(id+"\n");
fstream.close();
```

Test Plan:

1. HTTP Request GetUsersById => return all IDs
2. Json extractor => from my response

   ```
   {"@class":"com.test.dto.userDTO",
         "author":"John",
         "id":"89BC331D723F",  },


   {"@class":"com.test.dto.userDTO",
         "author":"Alex",
         "id":"FTH7JBDRF567",
      }
   ```

   - Name of variale : userID
   - JSON path expression: `$.[?(@.@class=='com.test.dto.userDTO')].id`
   - Match Numbers:  `-1`
3. BeanShell Postprocessor

But my csv file is always empty and look like that:

[image]

Comment: probably you didn't set `userID`, show how you define/set the variable

Comment: I add a Debug Sampler and it displays : 'userID_1=89BC331D723F' and 'userID_2=FTH7JBDRF567'

Comment: so use `userID_1`

Comment: But in this case it will write only the first userID

Comment: follow this link to find solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364953/how-can-i-write-all-values-extracted-via-regex-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [vars](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) to get variable

```
String id = vars.get("userID");
```

> vars - (JMeterVariables) - gives read/write access to variables:
>   `vars.get(key);`

And prefer using `JSR223 PostProcessor` over `Beanshell PostProcessor`

Answer (score 0):

```
String id  = vars.get("userID");
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("JmeterBean.csv",true);
fstream.write(id+"\n");
fstream.close();
```

I did it but i got the same result with `null` in my csv file:

[image: CSV file]

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be an edit to your question

Answer (score 0):

1. If the JSON Extractor produces more than 1 match you don't have the `userID` variable, you will have something like:

   ```
   userID_1=89BC331D723F
   userID_2=FTH7JBDRF567
   userID_matchNr=2
   ```

   so I would recommend double checking which [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are produced by the JSON Extractor using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) combination.
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

Assuming all above add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) (make sure it's located **after** the JSON Extractor) and use the following code:

```
1.upto(vars.get('userID_matchNr') as int, { number ->
    new File('JmeterBean.csv') << vars.get('userID_' + number) << System.getProperty('line.separator')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#The below mentioned solution worked for me: 

OrderID = vars.get("primaryRefID");
FileWriter fstream = new 
FileWriter("C://Users/Documents/JMeter/OrderID.csv",true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write("TC-"+OrderID);
out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
out.close();
fstream.close();
```

Comment: Try giving the absolute path to your JmeterBean.csv file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).